# How to know where live point is in a stream?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, live, flash-media-server, netstream

How to know where live point is in a stream?

NetStream.seek ( 99999999999999 ) basically sends me to the latest point, but how do I  find the current exact endpoint of the stream?

Answer (score 0):

found it now, on the Client

onMetaData()

info.duration

else its netstream.time.